# Bar fill and Bar unfilled doesn't ovelap

Tags: html, css, progress

I am trying to create a CSS progress bar however for some reason the UNFILL part (white background) doesn't overlap with the green background which is the FILL part.

Any idea how to make it like that?

Also which browser this should ONLY or WILL NOT work for since this is a @Keyframe CSS3?

CSS:

```
.container{
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.bar{
  width: 100%;
  background: #141414;
  padding: 17px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.bar-fill{
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
  background: #45c9a5;
  width: 0%;
  border-radius: 8px;

  -webkit-transition: width 0.8s ease;
  transition: width 0.8s ease;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; 
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}


.bar-unfill{
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {width: 0%;}
    to {width: 100%;}
} 

/* Standard syntax */ 
@keyframes mymove {
   from {width: 0%;}
    to {width: 100%;}
}



.title{
 background: #545965;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 15px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 right: 60px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

Here is the JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/xdbb3ypc/1/

Thanks!

Please provide JSFIDDLE ALSO

Comment: Could you please edit your question with a little snippet of code, so that we can try to understand the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just position 'filled' part inside 'unfilled', ie something like that:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="title">Testing</div>
    <div class="bar">
        <span class="bar-unfill">
            <span class="bar-fill"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should position the filled bar inside the unfilled bar, to allow it to be drawn on top of it

```
<div class="container">
<div class="title">Testing</div>
  <div class="bar">
    <span class="bar-unfill">
        <span class="bar-fill"></span>
    </span>    
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z4kn3p40/